# Client software to allow employees to access network via Cisco VPN for Windows

Tags: vpn, windows-10

I am absolutely shocked at this.

We have a Cisco router running an IPSEC VPN server, and normally our employees VPN in via Cisco's old VPN software (I forget the name of it; but it is old software). Now, we are starting to upgrade employees to Win10, which does not support this. Only **Cisco Anyconnect** supports this.

Unfortunately, we do not have a support contract with our Cisco router, therefore we are NOT able to download the Anyconnect software. I've tried using a few VPN software packages (Win10 has a built in VPN client that obviously doesn't work well, or I'm not using it right), but none of them will work with this Cisco server, since it requires group authentication credentials.

I have mac employees and linux employees that can access, so I know it isn't a proprietary thing.

**So my question is: How can I connect to a Cisco VPN server as a client that does NOT use the Cisco Anyconnect Client vpn software?  Is there any other client vpn software available?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shrew Soft VPN](https://www.shrew.net/software) works on Windows 10, even if it is not officially supported yet.

Comment: I personally couldn't get Shrew Soft to work, however based on popularity it seems that this does in fact work, and I likely just messed up.  No longer with the company anymore so I can't test this out.  Marking as answered.